# Make Rails Class Attribute Inaccessible - Rails Tutorial Chapter 9, Exercise 1 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I've come to [Chapter 9, Exercise 1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3aupdating_deleting_exercises). It asks you to add a test to verify that the `admin` attribute of the `User` class is not accessible. Here's the User class with irrelevant portions commented out:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_protected :admin

  # before_save methods
  # validations
  # private methods
end
```

And here's the test I'm using to validate that the `admin` attribute is not accessible.

```
describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new( 
                     name: "Example User",
                     email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar123",
                     password_confirmation: "foobar123")
  end

  subject { @user }

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to admin" do
      expect do
        @user.admin = true 
      end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails. It says no errors were raised, in spite of the fact that the `admin` attribute is protected. How can I get the test to pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Ruby documentation:

> Mass assignment security provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Try this code instead

```
describe "accesible attributes" do
  it "should not allow access to admin" do
    expect do
      User.new(admin: true) 
    end.should raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

As Rails docs claim about attr_protected

> Attributes named in this macro are protected from mass-assignment, such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes), or attributes=(attributes).

So you can change field manually. 'attr_protected' is only about mass-assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This only works for mass assignments like setting the field from a form submit. Try something like this:

```
@user.update_attrtibutes(:admin => true)
@user.admin.should be_false
```

Answer (score 1):

@agaved. This answer may come late and you may already have the answer but I wanted to answer your question, it may help somebody else.

The best way to understand how `update_attributes` differs from direct assignment 
`@user.admin = true` is to try and do it in your console. If you are following Hartl's tutorial, try the following:

```
@user = User.first
@user.admin?
=> true
@user.admin = false
=> false
```

Direct assignment manages to change the value of the attribute admin for user from `true` to `false` without raising a Mass Assignment Error. This is because Mass Assignment Errors are raised when you call `update_attributes` or create a new user `User.new` using an attribute that is not accessible. In other words, Rails raises mass assignment errors when a user tries to update `(attribute_update)` or create `User.new(admin: true)` a new user with attributes that are not accessible to her. In the above case, direct assignment is not using the create or update methods of the user controller.

They are very similar pieces of code since you can use direct assignment to force a change in the admin attribute in the above case using `@user.save!(validate: false)` directly in IRB but as I said above this does not use the create or update method of your user controller and, hence, it will not throw the error.

I hope that helps, [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) helped me.

Answer (score 1):

[Spoiler alert: If you are trying to solve the exercises in Hartl's book on your own, I'm pretty sure I'm about to give the answer away. Even though the answer that has been accepted is interesting information, I don't believe it was what Hartl had in mind as that would require knowledge the book has not covered and also does not relate it specifically to updates via web action or use the test he provides.]

I think you might be thinking this exercise is a lot harder than it actually is, if I got it right. First of all, you have misunderstood the hint:

> Hint: Your first step should be to add admin to the list of permitted parameters in user_params.

It does not say to change its attr declaration in the class. It says to modify the helper function user_params. So I added it to the list in users_controller.rb:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                             :password_confirmation, :admin)
end
```

Next, I copied the code in Listing 9.48 to the indicated place in spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do
  .
  .
  .
  describe "edit" do
    .
    .
    .
    describe "forbidden attributes" do
      let(:params) do
        { user: { admin: true, password: user.password,
                  password_confirmation: user.password } }
      end
      before do
        sign_in user, no_capybara: true
        patch user_path(user), params
      end
      specify { expect(user.reload).not_to be_admin }
    end
  end
end
```

The test then fails, showing that it is possible to pass in an admin parameter and thus change a normal user to an admin, which is not what you would want to allow:

```
$ rspec spec
.....................[edited out dots].................................F

Failures:

  1) User pages edit forbidden attributes 
     Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload).not_to be_admin }
       expected admin? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:180:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 4.15 seconds
91 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:180 # User pages edit forbidden attributes
```

Then, to make it impossible to pass in an admin value via a web action, I simply removed :admin from the list of acceptable user_params, undoing the first change:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                             :password_confirmation)
end
```

Now the attempt to patch the user with a new admin value fails... and the test for it succeeds, verifying "that the `admin` attribute isn’t editable through the web."

```
    $ rspec spec
...........................................................................................

Finished in 4.2 seconds
91 examples, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint, I first added `:admin` to `attr_accessible` in app/models/user.rb to start with a red.

I then added the test:

```
describe "admin attribute" do
    it  "should not be accessible" do
        expect do
            @user.update_attributes(:admin => true)
        end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
end
```

to the spec and got a red.

Removing `:admin` from user.rb I get a green. So far so good.

What puzzles me is why I should use the sintax:

```
@user.update_attributes(:admin => true)
```

instead of `@user.admin = true` (I checked and in this case it doesn't work).